Prevent click outside of the toggle
This is my code for toggle. But when I click outside of the toggle also its working.
I want to prevent that.It should enable or disable when click the toggle check box only.
<div class="slds-form-element">
            <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
                <span class="slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom_none">Retain Ownership</span>
                <input disabled="{!v.toggle}" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle-16" checked="{!v.isToggleChecked}" value="{!v.isToggleChecked}" onchange="{!c.handleToggleChange}" aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-16" />
                <span id="checkbox-toggle-16" class="slds-checkbox_faux_container">
                    <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                    <span class="slds-checkbox_on">Retained</span>
                    <span class="slds-checkbox_off">Disabled</span>
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>

Could anyone please help me on this?
Thank You,
Thiru

Issue Description:
This happening because the event is found in full width of that checkbox. So anywhere you click on the area it toggles the checkbox on and off.

So, the workaround found about this is make the width of slds-checkbox_toggle to 0 by adding style="width: 0" to your label and it should work and only allow clicking on the checkbox.
Sample Code:
Component
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="isToggleChecked" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="toggle" type="Boolean" default="false" />

    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid" style="width: 0">
            <span class="slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom_none">Retain Ownership</span>
            <input 
                disabled="{!v.toggle}" 
                type="checkbox" 
                name="checkbox-toggle-16" 
                checked="{!v.isToggleChecked}" 
                value="{!v.isToggleChecked}" 
                onchange="{!c.handleToggleChange}" 
                aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-16" />
            <span id="checkbox-toggle-16" class="slds-checkbox_faux_container">
                <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-checkbox_on">Retained</span>
                <span class="slds-checkbox_off">Disabled</span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</aura:component>

JS Controller:
({
    handleToggleChange: function (component, event, helper) {
        if (event.target && event.target.type === "checkbox") {
            let isChecked = event.target.checked;
            component.set("v.isToggleChecked", isChecked);
        }
    }
})


Thank you so much. It is working now
